# androidError:(18, 18) error: Adapter is abstract; cannot be instantiated

Tags: java, android

I am a newbie android developer.
I was trying to build an android application that displays an image slider.
I used 'Adapter' and tried to instantiate the Adapter object 'adapter'.
However, error message pop out, said, 'Error:(18, 18) error: Adapter is abstract; cannot be instantiated.'.
I had searched the solution for this problem, and someone in Stackoverflow said to instantiate Adapter, first the Adapter class should inherited PageAdapter class. I did as following, however, same error is appearing yet. What is wrong with my code?
Below is the 'Adapter.java', the code for Adapter class.

```
package com.example.clee.tutorial9;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class Adapter extends PagerAdapter {

private int[] images= {R.drawable.one, R.drawable.two, R.drawable.three};
//one, two, three are the name of the images.

private LayoutInflater inflater;
private Context context;

public Adapter(Context context){
    this.context= context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return images.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view==((LinearLayout) object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position){
    inflater= (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.slider, container, false);
    ImageView imageview= (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    TextView textview= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    imageview.setImageResource(images[position]);
    textview.setText((position +1) + "image.");
    container.addView(v);
    return v;
   }

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object){
    container.invalidate();
   }
}
```

And this is the code of 'MainActivity.java'.

```
package com.example.clee.tutorial9;

import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Adapter;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Adapter adapter;
ViewPager viewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    viewPager= (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view);
    adapter= new Adapter(this);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Errors are found in 19th and 20th statement of 'MainActivity.java'.
To sum up, I have two errors in the code.

1. Adaper is abstract: cannot be instantiated.
2. incompatible type: Adapter cannot be converted to PageAdapter.

Comment: did you find a better answer to your question??

Answer (score 2):

Rename your adapter class to `CustomAdapter` or any other name.
Because you are currently referring to `android.widget.Adapter`

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong Adapter class since you are importing the wrong package: `android.widget.Adapter;`

import this instead:

```
com.example.clee.tutorial9.Adapter
```

an even better, dont define your classes with already defined ones in the SDK, so rename your ***Adapter*** to ***MyAppAdampter***  and import

```
com.example.clee.tutorial9.MyAppAdampter
```